# Can unique_lock be used with a recursive_mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, recursive-mutex

According the [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), `unique_lock` can be used for recursive locking by declaring a `std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex>`, and in fact that compiles fine.

However, it appears from examining the code (gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9.0) that `unique_lock` doesn't defer to `_Mutex.lock`, but rather implements the lock method itself:

```
  void
  lock()
  {
if (!_M_device)
  __throw_system_error(int(errc::operation_not_permitted));
else if (_M_owns)
  __throw_system_error(int(errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur));
else
  {
    _M_device->lock();
    _M_owns = true;
  }
```

Clearly, this prevents recursive locking of the mutex, and in fact attempting to recursively lock throws the `resource_deadlock_would_occur` exception.

Am I missing something here, is this a bug, or is the documentation for unique_lock just wrong?

TIA!!!

Answer (score 32):

A common mistake is to confuse the `mutex` with the `lock`.  A `mutex` is an object that can be shared among threads (otherwise it would be useless).  A lock however is not itself a thread-safe object.  It should not be shared among threads.  It is typically a local object on a stack.  For example:

```
void foo()
{
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);  // mut comes from some other scope
     // mut locked here
     // ...
}    // mut unlocked here
```

In the example above, if `foo()` is called recursively, you have undefined behavior because you will lock `mut` recursively.  On each recursion, you get a new `unique_lock` though.  So the `unique_lock` is not aware of the recursion.  If you really need to call `foo()` recursively, you need to use a recursive mutex, for example:

```
void foo()
{
     std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lk(mut);  // mut comes from some other scope
     // mut locked here
     // ...
}    // mut unlocked here
```

So:  Yes, you can use `std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex>`, and yes, your implementation is correct.

Comment: Thanks, Howard!  That makes things much clearer.  Prob. should have been obvious from reading the code, but the fact that unique_lock is intended to be allocated on the stack didn't jump out at me.

Comment: Excellent answer. The answer is simple and the concepts are simple, however it's quite easy to get things mixed up!