# Program returned: 143 when thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a method:

```
void move_robot(const vector<vector<double> > &map) {
    // accumulate the footprint while the robot moves
    // Iterate through the path
        //std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        for (unsigned int i=1; i < map.size(); i++) {

            while (distance(position , map[i]) > DISTANCE_TOLERANCE ) {
                this->direction = unitary_vector(map[i], this->position);
                this->next_step();
                lck.unlock();
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10)); // sleep for 500 ms
                lck.lock();
            }
            std::cout << "New position is x:" << this->position[0] << " and y:" << this->position[1] << std::endl;
        }
        this->moving = false;
        // notify to end
    }
```

When the sleep and locks are included I get:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 143

Killed - processing time exceeded
```

Nevertheless, if I comment all the locks and `this_thread::sleep_for` it works as expected.
I need the locks because I am dealing with other threads. The complete code is this one: https://godbolt.org/z/7ErjrG
I am quite stacked because the otput does not provide much information

Comment: Please put the minimal necessary code in the question. I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: If you get this message in godbolt it might mean that godbolt has some limitations of executing time and your code executes for too long.

Comment: And why are you using a std::vector for a simple x-y tuple/ location?

Comment: what would you use? JOBonarius

Answer (score 1):

You have not posted the code of `next_step` and the definition of `mtx`, this is important information.

```
std::mutex mtx;

void next_step() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  this->position[0] += DT * this->direction[0];
  this->position[1] += DT * this->direction[1];
}
```

If you read the manual for [std::mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) you find out:

- A calling thread must not own the mutex prior to calling lock or try_lock.

And [std::unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unique_lock):

3. Locks the associated mutex by calling m.lock(). The behavior is undefined if the current thread already owns the mutex except when the mutex is recursive.

`next_step` called from `move_robot` violates this, it tries to lock already owned mutex object by that calling thread.

The relative topic for your question is [Can unique_lock be used with a recursive_mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626290/can-unique-lock-be-used-with-a-recursive-mutex). There you get the fix:

```
std::recursive_mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> lck(mtx);
```

Comment: Can I just remove it from `next_step` ? as the function calling it already has it locked

Comment: Of course you can. You can also move `lck.unlock();` one line up.